# Script to duplicate inactive sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have this script below, which works very well to duplicate a sheet and rename it from the contents of cell A3.

Now I would like to run this exact function, but on an inactive (or even hidden) sheet. It can be a duplicate with only values copied, as there is no need to copy all of the deep data.

```js
function AddReportSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
    var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet( ).getRange("A3").getDisplayValue();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
}
```

Comment: You want to duplicate all non active sheets ? Or particular sheets ?

Comment: @Marios I only want to duplicate one particular sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to duplicate a particular sheet and set the name of the duplicate based on the value of cell `A3` of the original sheet.

- Use [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to get a particular sheet by its name.
- You can use the [sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) method to achieve your goal and chain it with [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setName(String)) to set the name of the sheet according to the value of cell `A3`.

### Solutions:

**Duplicate the sheet:**

Select the name of the sheet you want to duplicate. In the following example, `Sheet1`:

```
function AddReportSheet() {   
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // put the name of your sheet to duplicate
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const myValue = sheet.getRange('A3').getDisplayValue();
    sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(myValue);   
}
```

**Duplicate the sheet and keep only the values and format:**

If you want to keep only the values of the duplicate sheet then you can use the [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)) and keep only the contents e.g. `{contentsOnly:true}`.

```
function AddReportSheet() {   
    const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // put the name of your sheet to duplicate
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const myValue = sheet.getRange('A3').getDisplayValue();
    const new_sheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(myValue);   
    const rng = new_sheet.getDataRange();
    rng.copyTo(rng, {contentsOnly:true})
}
```